# How to get a JSON field by passing all path as a parameter

Tags: java, json

I have a json :

```
"employee": {
    "firstName": "Brian",
    "lastName": "Schultz",
    "website": "example.com"
}
```

In Jackson to get "firstName" I must do this:

```
JsonNode idNode = rootNode.path("employee").path("firstName");
```

I would like to do something like this: `path("employee/firstName")`

I do not see "at" method in my Jackson class.

Could you tell me how to do this or tell me other lib instead of Jackson ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [jsonpath](https://jsonpath.com).

There are two libraries to use:

1. Standalone (https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
2. Part of the RestAssured (https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted#jsonpath)

In case, you do not want to use the same way to query both XML and JSON, I would suggest to use the first one/

Comment: Using JsonPath, when I need to check if path exist or not in json I must do this. Suppressing exceptions looks bad. Do you know how to write this more correctly?

boolean pathExist(String json, String path) {

    Configuration conf = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS);


    if (JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json).read(path) != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }}

Comment: private static final String json = "{\"employee\": {\"firstName\": \"Brian\", \"lastName\": \"Schultz\",  \"website\": \"example.com\",\"badges\": []}}";

    @Test
    void invalidPath() {
        final DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.using(Configuration.builder().options(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL).build()).parse(json);  assertEquals("Brian", documentContext.read("$.employee.firstName"));
        assertNull(documentContext.read("$.employee.secondName"));
    }